# Cesium Equirectangular Projection Wrapping Issues

Tags: mapping, cesiumjs

I am attempting to create markers with labels, that only appear at certain zoom levels within Cesium.  When using the 3D view, everything works as expected.  However, when switching to the 2D (equirectangular) projection, I am experiencing a number of issues related to the the anti-meridian (180 degree longitude):

- The markers are cutoff when they span the anti-meridian.
- When the anti-meridian is visible on screen, the distanceDisplayCondition is exhibiting strange behavior depending on whether a point falls on the "large" side (portion to one side of the anti-meridian that occupies over 50% of the width) or "small" side (portion to one side of the anti-meridian that occupies less than 50% of the width).  In both cases, it appears the distance calculation being performed by CESIUM isn't being done correctly when the anti-meridian is visible.

  - Small: Markers on this side are visible well before they become visible on the "large" side.
  - Large: Markers on this side are visible slightly prior to when they ought to be displayed.  Steps to reproduce: zoom into a portion of the map where the anti-meridian is NOT visible.  Once you see the markers, zoom out a single step.  Now pan the map until the anti-meridian is visible and about 10% into the screen space.  The markers on the "large" side will suddenly appear.

The following images illustrate these bugs.  The first shows a zoom level in Cesium with the anti-meridian barely visible within the frame.  The second shows the exact same scene, at the same zoom level, moved about 4 pixels to the left.  If the scene is moved far enough left where the anti-meridian is near the left edge of the screen, then the markers to the right of the anti-meridian disappear while the markers on the left stay on screen.  Both images show how the markers are cut-off at the anti-meridian, and in both cases, none of the markers should be visible.
[image: Only markers to the right of the anti-meridian are incorrectly shown]
[image: None of these markers should be visible]

The JavaScript required to reproduce this in Sandcastle is:

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {timeline : false, animation : false});

for (var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    viewer.entities.add({
        position: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromRadians(
            Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI, Math.asin(2 * Math.random() - 1)),
        point   : {
            color: Cesium.Color.RED,
            pixelSize: 36,
            distanceDisplayCondition: new Cesium.DistanceDisplayCondition(0, 10000000)
        },
        label: {
            text: '222',
            font: '16px Monospace',
            eyeOffset: new Cesium.Cartesian3(0, 0, -100),
            style: Cesium.LabelStyle.FILL_AND_OUTLINE
        }
    });
}
```

Does anyone know of a way to work-around these Cesium bugs?